# tried everything, but cant find a way to change the font size of QTableView, how do i do this?

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5, alignment, font-size

how do i change the **font size** in the dataframe table and possibly **align** the values in the table 'center'????
i've searched all over and tried many of the examples/suggestions and theyve not worked.

**ok so heres my code below:**

```
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data  

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
            return str(value)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]
        
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])
    
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('logo.png'))
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        data = df
        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.setWindowTitle(windowtitle)
        self.table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(
        QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.table.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(80)
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) #date
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) #rank
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) #name
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(3, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) #symbol
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(4, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) #price
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(5, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) #change 1h
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(6, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) #change 24h
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(7, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) #change 7d
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(8, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) #volume 24h
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(8, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) #market cap
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(8, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch) #performance
        self.showMaximized()
            
app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
#window.resize(2112, 1200)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

any help is much appreciated and thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Could you show the df data?

Comment: What did you actually try? There's no such attempt in your code. Also, should the font and alignment be changed for all items, or follow specific "rules"? Finally, calling `setSectionResizeMode` for each section is pointless (not to mention that you also repeated the same call three times). Just set it for all by removing the column index: `setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)`.

Comment: of course my 'attempts' wont be present in the code above, none of them worked causing the program to break or the attempt didnt break the program but also didnt do anything. i use the program daily as part of my trading arsenal, so naturally im not going to keep code in that breaks the program, but after a week of trying countless answers on stackoverflow, youtube tutorials and on blogs etc has left me stuck, hence why im here asking. the request was for the font-size and alignment to be all columns and cells.

Comment: well spotted on the 3 calls though!

Comment: @crypto-simon The point is, if we knew what you tried, we could better guide you in understanding what was the problem, which is far more useful than just providing an answer, not only to you, but to anyone that might be facing the same problem. Of course you shouldn't use buggy code in production, but you're also not expected to show a [mre] that uses your production code, you're supposed to provide the actual code that creates you problems. Btw, use [`setFont()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#font-prop), and return the appropriate alignment when the role of `data()` is `TextAlignmentRole`.

Comment: forget it, i'll just struggle on by myself and try another 5000 code attempts, i thought coders were friendly and willing to help rookie coders, well i guess theres always one.......youve clearly proved this!!